# Congruence of Euler numbers modulo Fermat numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, generating-functions, congruences

The exponential generating function of the unsigned Euler numbers $E_{n}$ is
 $$\frac{1}{\cos x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{ E_n}{n!}x^n$$
For $k,n\gt0$, not too large, one can observe that 
$$E_{ 2^{2^k}\cdot n} \equiv 0 \mod (2^{2^k}+1) $$
For $k,n\gt0$, I would say more:

$$E_{ 2n} \equiv 0 \mod (2^{2^k}+1) \Longleftrightarrow n \equiv 0 \mod2^{2^k}    $$

Is this true?

UPDATE: this is true in the $\Longleftarrow$ direction, when $2^{2^k}+1$ is prime since it can be shown that

> $$E_{2 m}\equiv 0 \ \  \bmod \prod_{\begin{array}{c} p\equiv 1 \bmod 4
>  \\  p-1\mid 2m  \end{array}}p$$

where $p$ is a prime and the product is $1$ when there is no factor.

But this is wrong in general because it can also be shown that

> $$E_{2 m+p-1}\equiv E_{2 m} \ \  \bmod p $$

where $p$ is odd prime.

$2^{2^5}+1=641\cdot 6700417$

$2^{2^5} \equiv 256 \ \  \bmod 640 $

then $E_{2^{2^5}}\equiv E_{256}\equiv 560 \ \  \bmod 641 $

therefore $E_{2^{2^5}}$ is not divisible by $641$, hence $E_{2^{2^5}}$ is not divisible by $2^{2^5}+1$ either.